# How to link to a hardware barcode scanner?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk

So i have this barcode scanner integrated with an android phone, it's a scanner+phone kind of thing.

Picked it up from somewhere and it doesn't come with any manual, but it has this scanner demo app inside it which is working with the scanner. Is there any chance i can build my own app, link up the scanner and my app and run it? Lots of tutorial out there is teaching how to integrate the camera as a barcode scanner so im just wondering here.

Anything helps, just a discussion among the minds.

[EDIT] so i have found 2 different libraries that might help in anywhere, ZBAR and ZXING, is there anyone out there who managed to link use these libraries along with your HARDWARE SCANNER (not your mobile phone)?

Comment: Could you be more specific than "picked it up from somewhere"? Knowing where you found it is important to find out how it works and how you can use it.

Comment: Does it have a brand and type name? Maybe there is some documentation on the Web.

Comment: Found it in a box where my brother left it, no documentations, NLSCAN is the company brand, apparently it's from china. Maybe i can send over an email requesting for the documentations if its possible (but idk if there will handle over anything considering im like 'breaking' their product.)